# SwiftUI create image slider with dots as indicators

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to create a scroll view/slider for images. See my example code:

```
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: true) {
      HStack {
           Image(shelter.background)
               .resizable()
               .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 300)
           Image("pacific")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 300)
      }
}
```

**Though this enables the user to slide, I want it a little different (similar to a PageViewController in UIKit). I want it to behave like the typical image slider we know from a lot of apps with dots as indicators:**

1. It shall always show a full image, no in between - hence if the user drags and stops in the middle, it shall automatically jump to the full image.
2. I want dots as indicators.

Since I've seen a lot of apps use such a slider, there must be known method, right?

Comment: In the tutorial [Interfacing with UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit) Apple demos exactly how to do what you've asked for.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

There is no built-in method for this in SwiftUI this year. I'm sure a system-standard implementation will come along in the future.

In the short term, you have two options. As Asperi noted, Apple's own tutorials have a section on wrapping the PageViewController from UIKit for use in SwiftUI (see [Interfacing with UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit)).

The second option is to roll your own. It's entirely possible to make something similar in SwiftUI. Here's a proof of concept, where the index can be changed by swipe or by binding:

```
struct PagingView<Content>: View where Content: View {

    @Binding var index: Int
    let maxIndex: Int
    let content: () -> Content

    @State private var offset = CGFloat.zero
    @State private var dragging = false

    init(index: Binding<Int>, maxIndex: Int, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self._index = index
        self.maxIndex = maxIndex
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    HStack(spacing: 0) {
                        self.content()
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                            .clipped()
                    }
                }
                .content.offset(x: self.offset(in: geometry), y: 0)
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, alignment: .leading)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture().onChanged { value in
                        self.dragging = true
                        self.offset = -CGFloat(self.index) * geometry.size.width + value.translation.width
                    }
                    .onEnded { value in
                        let predictedEndOffset = -CGFloat(self.index) * geometry.size.width + value.predictedEndTranslation.width
                        let predictedIndex = Int(round(predictedEndOffset / -geometry.size.width))
                        self.index = self.clampedIndex(from: predictedIndex)
                        withAnimation(.easeOut) {
                            self.dragging = false
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
            .clipped()

            PageControl(index: $index, maxIndex: maxIndex)
        }
    }

    func offset(in geometry: GeometryProxy) -> CGFloat {
        if self.dragging {
            return max(min(self.offset, 0), -CGFloat(self.maxIndex) * geometry.size.width)
        } else {
            return -CGFloat(self.index) * geometry.size.width
        }
    }

    func clampedIndex(from predictedIndex: Int) -> Int {
        let newIndex = min(max(predictedIndex, self.index - 1), self.index + 1)
        guard newIndex >= 0 else { return 0 }
        guard newIndex <= maxIndex else { return maxIndex }
        return newIndex
    }
}

struct PageControl: View {
    @Binding var index: Int
    let maxIndex: Int

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 8) {
            ForEach(0...maxIndex, id: \.self) { index in
                Circle()
                    .fill(index == self.index ? Color.white : Color.gray)
                    .frame(width: 8, height: 8)
            }
        }
        .padding(15)
    }
}
```

and a demo

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var index = 0

    var images = ["10-12", "10-13", "10-14", "10-15"]

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            PagingView(index: $index.animation(), maxIndex: images.count - 1) {
                ForEach(self.images, id: \.self) { imageName in
                    Image(imageName)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                }
            }
            .aspectRatio(4/3, contentMode: .fit)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))

            PagingView(index: $index.animation(), maxIndex: images.count - 1) {
                ForEach(self.images, id: \.self) { imageName in
                    Image(imageName)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                }
            }
            .aspectRatio(3/4, contentMode: .fit)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))

            Stepper("Index: \(index)", value: $index.animation(.easeInOut), in: 0...images.count-1)
                .font(Font.body.monospacedDigit())
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image: PagingView demo]

Two notes:

1. The GIF animation does a really poor job of showing how smooth the animation is, as I had to drop the framerate and compress heavily due to file size limits. It looks great on simulator or a real device
2. The drag gesture in the simulator feels clunky, but it works really well on a physical device.

Comment: Apple's `PageViewController` sample raises more questions (for me) than it answers. Maybe after this example (the most illuminating SwiftUI example I've seen yet) it will be clearer.

Comment: This is awesome. How could I implement an autoplay system?

Comment: I found an issue, if I have this in a scrollview I can't scroll up or down if my finger is over the PagingView

Comment: @FilipeSá add `private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 3, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()` under `let content: () -> Content`, and then `.onReceive(self.timer) { _ in
                self.index = (self.index + 1) % 3
            }` underneath `PageControl(index: $index, maxIndex: maxIndex)`.

Comment: @John M. Great Solution! Thank you. I would suggest embedding the PageControl in HStack and surrounding it with a Spacer, so it is centered.

Comment: I also found an issue. When the image is set to `.scaleToFill()`, The actual dragging area is the original image area. As a result, the image is still draggable way above itself on some empty area.

Comment: @FilipeSá change to `DragGesture(minimumDistance: 30, coordinateSpace: .local)` to enable up down scroll as well

Comment: `let v = Mirror(reflecting: content()).descendant("value")`
`let tm = Mirror(reflecting: v!)`
`self.maxIndex = tm.children.count - 1`

you can remove `maxIndex` from `init` this way

Comment: also please add `.allowsHitTesting(false)` on hstack so the clipped content doesn't interfere with other gestures on the screen

Comment: Is there a way to add a tap gesture on it ? I tried but looks like it has conflicts with the Drag gesture

Answer (score 7):

### You can easily achieve this by below code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    public let timer = Timer.publish(every: 3, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State private var selection = 0
    
    ///  images with these names are placed  in my assets
    let images = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack{
            
            Color.black
            
            TabView(selection : $selection){
                
                ForEach(0..<5){ i in
                    Image("\(images[i])")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                }

                
            }.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
            .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
            .onReceive(timer, perform: { _ in
                    
                withAnimation{
                    print("selection is",selection)
                    selection = selection < 5 ? selection + 1 : 0
                }                
            })  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but you cant put it inside a navigationView

Comment: UI lags when TabView is placed inside a ScrollView. I'd love to hear some comments on how can we improve it?

Comment: this has iOS 14 restriction, otherwise this is best native approach

Comment: this is not working as an auto slider. how I can achieve as same as auto image slider automatically after every 2 seconds and data is coming from server?